# Map Varchar column type to Integer in entity jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have legacy table in which one of its column's type is varchar but there is all numbers in it. I don't want to change datatype in table. I want to change the column data type in entity.

Before it was string now i changed it to Integer and crud operations are working fine.  Is this fine doing or there is some other way of doing it?  Sample code:

**Before:**

```java
@Entity
public class TestEntity{
    @Column(name = "Test")
    private String test;
}
```

**Now:**

```java
@Entity
public class TestEntity{
    @Column(name = "Test")
    private Integer test;
}
```

Comment: Your before and after code is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `AttributeConverter` which will be use for Database to entity type converstion

```
@Converter
public class IntegerToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter < Integer,
 String > {
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Integer value) {
   return Integer.toString(number);
  }

  @Override
  public Integer convertToEntityAttribute(String number) {
   try {
    return Integer.parseInt(number);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid number: " + value);
   }
  }
 }
```

And use it on your column

```
@Convert(converter = IntegerToStringConverter.class)
@Column(name = "Test")
private Integer Test;
```

Comment: I am not using any converter i just changed the datatype, and its cruds are working fine. Still Do i need to make explicit converter for that column?

Comment: Can you check data for this column persist properly or not ? Changing only datatype may not work. Use various data for this column

Comment: Yes i checked data is persisting properly.  I tried null, and various digits and its persisting and reading fine without using any converter

Comment: If there is some data in column that cannot be parsed to Integer then jpa will throw exception, To handle that case explicitly i need to implement Converter.

Comment: Yes, maybe Jpa autoboxing but to handle the exception you need this.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it via getter/setter for the field in the database and applying `@Transient` annotation to the integer property.

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Column(name = "test") 
    private  String getTest() {
        return String.valueOf(this.intTest);
    }

    private void setTest(String test) {
        try {
            this.intTest = Integer.parseInt(test);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            this.intTest = 0;
        }
    }

    @Transient
    private int intTest;

    public int getIntTest() { return intTest; }

    public void setIntTest(int test) {
        this.intTest = intTest;
    }
}
```